# What is a good workflow when using speedgrade and transitions and effects in Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere, color-correction, transitions, color-grading, speedgrade

I want to try using speedgrade to get an overall cinematic look and I've heard that it is preferable to do speedgrade work before aadding any transitions or effects in PP. When I import from speedgrade to PP ( using an image sequence which I heard was the most typical/professional way to do it ) it has the sequence as a single clip in PP. What would I do at that point? Would I spit the single clip back into mutliple clips so I can add the transitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be possible to do it that way.
The best way I'm familiar with is actually the other way around.

1. You start a project in Adobe Premiere Pro
2. Use the "Direct-Link" function to import your Premiere project into Speedgrade.
3. Now, all editorial changes from premiere will update into Speedgrade.

   A lot of Speedgrade functions will disappear (raw debayering for instance)
   That is because Premiere is now "the boss" over Speedgrade and you should change those in Premiere.

Sorry for the bad news, but this is the only way I know, how what you ask is possibe.